# dataframe multiple column extract with changes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'length':    [ 3,  29, 40, 50, 75],
    'width': [94, 170, 80, 150, 120],
    'height': [31, 115, 90, 200, 130],
    'weight': [100, 110, 200, 140, 210],
    'cost' : [25, 30, 10, 50, 78],
    'dest': ['usa', 'usa', 'sa', 'eu', 'sa']
})
```

I want to create a smaller df just using the 'cost' and 'dest' columns, however, I want to modify the 'dest' column with something like
new_df = df['dest'].replace({"usa": "North America", "sa": "South America"})
How can I add the 'cost' and modified 'dest' columns in one statement?  Furthermore, there may need to be an additional replace on the cost column.
I appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({"cost":df['cost'], 
                       "dest":df["dest"].
                           replace({"eu":"Europe", 
                                    "usa":"North America", 
                                    "sa":"South America"})})
```

Comment: Those brackets and braces get me every time.  Both solutions seem so easy, but are uncluttered and very straightforward.  I'm still getting comfortable with pandas.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary and them map the destination column to that dictionary as follows:

```
dic = {'usa':'North America', 'sa':'South America', 'eu':'Europe'}
df = df[['cost', 'dest']] #reduce dataframe to desired columns
df.dest = df.dest.map(dic) # replace dest values by mapping them to the dictionary
print(df)

#
   cost           dest
0    25  North America
1    30  North America
2    10  South America
3    50         Europe
4    78  South America
```